# Lozad lazy load plugin, images show broken link before loading

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, lazy-loading

I'm using the lazy load plugin lozad on a grid of images. When loading the page all the images appear with the broken link thumbnail for a second before loading. If I scroll down, when the row comes into view, they also show as broken links before fully loading. Is there something I can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set up rootMargin so that the images are loaded earlier.
look in the readme:

```
const observer = lozad('.lozad', {
    rootMargin: '10px 0px', // syntax similar to that of CSS Margin
    threshold: 0.1 // ratio of element convergence
});
observer.observe();
```

and you can also style the appearance from broken links, see: https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/